# Flexbox - how to set equal spaces between elements

Tags: flexbox, element, margin

I have unusual approach in using of Flexbox, it is "12 column" design, all works fine, exceptions are the spaces between flex elements, they look different while wrapped and aligned in row. How to fix this?

I play with margin, but it doesn't help:

```
margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;         ???????
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmpt/j7tk30bx/7/

UPDATE:

Idea of this Flexbox is as follows:

if there is a big screen "desktop/pad" i.e. min screen width 841px - do FLEX in 12 column different width system,
for the rest "mobile/small screens" i.e. screen width <841px put wrapper (row) in one full screen width row - one by one.

This works fine, very flexible for web design and putting element where ever you want.

But the problem is that margins(spaces) between FLEXBOX elements (ROW and COL wrappers) are different in those 2 modes and CSS margin parameter top/bottom for example adjusts the view in different way in these 2 modes. I want to have spaces equal between FLEXBOX elements in the both modes.

NOTE:

```
margin: x 1% x 1%
```

is a strict rule to have  perfect 12 column system
i.e.

```
.col_12 {width: 98%;}
```

1%+1%+98%=100%

but I do not know what to do with x (top/bottom) margins

```
body {
  background-color: #998;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

[class*="col_"] {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #eed;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  padding: 0em 0% 0em 0%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 841px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .col_1 {width: 6.3%;}
  .col_2 {width: 15.0%;}
  .col_3 {width: 23.0%;}
  .col_4 {width: 31.3%;}
  .col_5 {width: 40.0%;}
  .col_6 {width: 48.0%;}
  .col_7 {width: 56.3%;}
  .col_8 {width: 65.0%;}
  .col_9 {width: 73.0%;}
  .col_10 {width: 81.3%;}
  .col_11 {width: 90.0%;}
  .col_12 {width: 98%;}

  [class*="col_"] {
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
}


<div class="row">
  <div class="col_11">col_11</div>
  <div class="col_1">col_1</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col_2">col_2</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col_12">col_12</div>
</div>
```

cleaned it up... fiddle updated too

Comment: Yes I know about css-tricks and prefixes, but anyway what about the subject?

Comment: Then you should clean it up so we don't have to sift through dozens of lines of obsolete code. Show your volunteers a bit of respect.

Comment: Hi! I think you CSS in jsfiddle is not valid. Moreover, it is not quite clear what you want in output. When talking about space between the elements, do you want no space at all? Do you want the vertical space to be the same as the horizontal?

Comment: not necessarily, I want the spaces to be the same whether rows wrapped or not i.e. for example for desktop and mobile screens.

Comment: Mmmh when removing `@media all and (min-width: 841px) {` as it breaks the css, the space between elements seems the same between all elements. Sorry but I do not really see where you see different spaces. Does your HTML/CSS in jsfiddle really show this problem you have?

Comment: Yes, margin between flex elements are different, try to resize small results windows in fiddle and you will see how the space changes proportionally, I want it fixed size, if possible of course

Comment: Well then you can use `margin: 1px;` and it will always set the space to 1px, is it what you want?

Comment: it doesn't, read above please I have updated the content

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE- FIX !!!

I have fixed it: margin at bottom 'auto' in @media section helps. In other places we indicate fixed margin (20px in this example), must be in px, not %. Looks fantastic... Tiny and reliable FLEXBOX... Thanks!

```
[class*="col_"] {
margin: 20px 1% 20% 1%; 
}
...

@media all and (min-width: 841px) {
...
[class*="col_"] {
...
margin: 20px 1% auto 1%; 
...
}
...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmpt/j7tk30bx/